# ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU0._PDC due to previous error

Tags: boot, xubuntu, acpi

I installed xubuntu 20.04 on a friend's lenovo thinkpad T560.

Nearly every time the notebook powers on the first time, after showing BIOS und GRUB, the xubuntu logo doesn't appear.

The full error message I can find in last syslog is:

```
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU0._PDC due to previous error
(AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20190816/psparse-529)
```

When I boot second time, it works like a charm.
I tried `noacpi` as grub boot option, but nothing changed.

Comment: Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to see the current BIOS version, then go to the Lenovo web site and check for a newer BIOS. Report back.

Comment: Seems, they have an old bios version (1.26), the newest ist 1.37. I search an external DVD-Writer and will try it.

Comment: Please keep me posted.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't help. But we figured out, that it might be the wireless keyboard receiver. My friend is testing for some weeks another keyboard, and maybe this is the fault.

Comment: Thanks for the update!